# C++/C: Convert a string to initializer list

Tags: c++, list, initializer-list

I'm reading into a string `s = {1,2,3}` something that looks like an initializer list from a text file.

How can I do an assignment like `int a[3]={1,2,3}` without hardcoding it, using something like `int a[3]=s;` ?

Comment: You'll have to write code to parse the contents of the file into a sequence of numbers. There is no magical shortcut.

Comment: How else do you think it's possible to do it, except for writing C++ code to parse the contents of the file?

Comment: you cant simply turn text into code and execute it at runtime. Parse the numbers and assign them to the elements

Comment: I guess the OP is used to one of the many scripting languages where you can evaluate text as code. C++ is not like that however.

Comment: your question is missing some details/clarity. What exactly is in the file? `s = {1,2,3}` ? Or just `{1,2,3}` ?

Comment: Just {1,2,3} and i'm doing an assignment . I've asked because i think it's a common operation and maybe there is a list constructor or something like this that parse it for you

Comment: Sorry, but nothing that will automatically parse it for you at runtime. Write a function and you probably want to use `std::vector` rather than an array. Arrays are too stupid to be able to handle files with different numbers of entries.

Comment: By "without hard coding" do you mean you need to read the file every time the code is run, or  you just want to keep some big initialiser list out of your c++ file? The reason I ask is initialiser lists are constant - they cant be changed, which includes read from files at run time. I explained this in an answer but it got down voted to death over the meaning of "hardcode".

Comment: @Ash I dont get what you say. Can't I read `a`,`b`,`c` from a file and use `{a,b,c}` as initializer? I think thats what OP actually wants (and probably expects some magic that doesn't exist)

Answer (score 0):

As it's been said in the comments, the only way to do something like this in C++ is to manually write a parser. An example using `std::vector` (that you should use specially because of the lenght variability) could be the following:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<int> parse(const std::string& str){
  if(str.front() != '{' || str.back() != '}'){
    throw std::invalid_argument("vectors must be enclosed between braces");
  }
  std::vector<int> result;
  result.reserve(std::count(str.begin(), str.end(),',')+1); // this pays off for really big vectors
  std::stringstream stream(str.substr(1,str.size()-2));
  std::string element;
  while(getline(stream,element,',')){
    result.push_back(std::stoi(element));
  }
  return result;
}
```

If performance is not that important, this should do.

Comment: No instance of function template std::count matches the argument list. Commented this line because i wont have big vectors but i get the same error for the getline inside while

Comment: Sorry, I also had two other mistakes but they are fixed now

Comment: Any clue about how i can impove performance ? It works perfectly with small data but i'm looking to extend it to big data .

Comment: If you want performance, get rid of stringstream and iterate it manually, C-style... I'm not 100% sure how the code would be, but you can start from there, I hope it's useful